# how to avoid routing through local stack in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, routes, network-programming

I have the following environment: 2 hosts, each with 2 Ethernet interfaces connected to eachother (like on diagram below):

```
 +---------+               +---------+                     
 |      (1)+---------------+(2)      |    
 |  host1  |               |  host2  |
 |         |               |         |
 |      (3)+---------------+(4)      |
 +---------+               +---------+
```

I would like to write client/server socket tool that will open both client and server sockets on host1.
I would like client to send TCP packets through interface (1) and server to listen on interface (3), that packets will go through host2.

Normally Linux stack will route this packets through local TCP/IP stack without sending those to host2.

I have tried to use **SO_BINDTODEVICE** option for both server and client and it seems that server indeed is binded to interface (3) and is not listening localhost traffic. I have checked that client from host1 could not be accepted whereas client from host2 does.

Unfortunately client packets are not send out (even tcpdump on interface(1) don't see packets) through interface (1) to interface (2).
Of course routing is correct (i can ping (2) from (1), (4) from (1), (4) from (3) and so on).

My question is if this is possible to be implemented without using custom TCP/IP stack?

Maybe I should try to change destination IP address (from client) to be from outside network (and then will be sent using default gateway from interface (1) - interface (2)) and then in postrouting change those again to original ones? Is such solution possible to work?

I am writting my application in C under Debian.

Adding some more details and clarifications:

1. of course both pairs (1)--(2) and (3)--(4) are different subnets
2. what I want to achieve is (1)-->(2)-->(4)-->(3)
3. host2 is blackbox so I cant install there any packet forwarder (that will open listening socket on interface (2) and forward those to (3) through (4)) - this is exactely what I want to avoid

The main problem seems to be local delivery. When I open socket on host1 and want to connect to socket, that is listening on other address of the same host kernel just uses local stack to deliver packets. See netfilter diagram below:

```
 --->[1]--->[ROUTE]--->[3]--->[4]--->
             |            ^
             |            |
             |         [ROUTE]
             v            |
            [2]          [5]
             |            ^
             |            |
             v            |
```

Packets are going through [5] NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT and [2] NF_IP_LOCAL_IN whereas I want to force them to go through [4].

Comment: Just to understand you want your message path to be (1) --> (2) --> (4) --> (3) ?

Comment: You certainly don't need a custom TCP stack for this. Not sure it if's the best way, but you could do some network address translation on host2 that would map some unique IP address to the address of interface (3), and make sure packets to (3) from host2 are routed out via (4). Host1 would then connect to that unique IP address.

Comment: If one socket connects from (1) to (2) on a different machine and another socket connects (4) to (3) on the first machine, why would the Linux TCP stack skip sending packets via the network? How could the TCP stack _possibly_ know about this unusual topology and how could it _possibly_ know your intent?

Comment: Think about it this way: You want to let your wife (who is in the next room) know that dinner is ready, but she is angry with you and does not talk to you. So you decide to call your mother and tell her to tell her neighbour to call your wife. You dial your mother's number. Now... which telephone do you think will ring? Do you think it is reasonable to assume that the telephone company will make your wife's phone ring?

Comment: Lets add IP adresses for clarification. Let's assume that IP addres of interface (1) is 192.168.1.1 and IP address of interface (3) is 192.168.10.1. When I open socket and want to connect 192.168.10.1 kernel will know that it is local address of other interface on host1. If Linux kernel is the telephone company it just knows that I want to call my wife. The point is how to force it to call my mother , to call the neighbour first instead of direct call.

Comment: One more comment: (1) --> (2) --> (4) --> (3) is what I want to achieve. Aix: the problem is not routing on host2, but rather how to force Linux kernel to send client packet from interface (1) to host2 instead of doing internal routing. Normaly as described in previous comment if kernel will figure aut that I want to connect from socket on host1 to de facto socket also on host1 it will use local stack for this.

Answer (score 4):

*Untested (should work, but I may have missed something):*

Linux has several routing tables. Table **local** contains some routes that the kernel adds automatically for every IP address added to the host. You can see them with `ip route show table local`. Routes labeled as **local** indicate local routes that go through the loopback interface. You could delete that route and add a normal **unicast** route to replace it:

```
ip route del table local <ip> dev <NIC>
ip route add table local <ip> dev <NIC>
ip route flush cache
```

Now your 1st box will try to send IP datagrams to that IP address as if it was a remote address, e.g: it will use ARP. So, your 2nd box will have to either reply to the ARP requests if it is acting as a router or is doing proxy-ARP, or you will have to add an association to the ARP cache:

```
arp -s <ip> <MAC>
```

Then, you will probably have to disable **rp_filter** on the interfaces:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/<NIC>/rp_filter
```

Them again, if this doesn't work, you could probably set up something with L2 NAT, using **ebtables**.

Comment: Did you mean `unicast` instead of `local` on that second `ip` line?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: **local** is for the table name. I didn't actually specify the type of route in either command, for the first one the IP will probably be enough to select an unique route to delete, for the second one **unicast** is the default route type.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: and yes, I tested that part, the packet is seen on `tcpdump -ni eth0`. I didn't test the whole setup, I'm too lazy for that. Anyway, the OP probably needs neither the `ARP` part nor the `rp_filter` one.

Comment: @ninjalj: how did you bind client socket to specific interface? I was trying to modify local routing tables but still my client packets are dropped somewhere by the kernell (can't see anything on interface (1)).

Comment: @codewarrior: you don't need to bind to an interface, routing takes care of everything. At least IP datagrams should be sent using the specified interface, I haven't set up a second system, so haven't tested the receiving part, enable `log_martians` and look at the kernel log.

Comment: @ninjalj: could you write explicitly commands you are using to change those local routes (assuming that ip of Interface (1) is 192.168.0.10 and IP of Interface (2) is 192.168.1.10)? I have some problem - after doing this I cannot even ping the interface (response is Invalid argument) so I assume that I am doing something wrong. Also could you write how did you test this solution? I am trying eg. ssh 192.168.0.10 (also Invalid argument response).

Comment: @codewarrior: I only tried sending packets, not receiving them. What's the relevant output of `ip address show`, `ip rule show`,`ip route show`, `ip route show table local`, `arp -an`, `tcpdump -ni eth0`, `tcpdump -ni eth1` ? Any firewall rules?

Answer (score 2):

For a very similar task I'm using such script:

```
ip rule add from all lookup local # add one more local table lookup rule with high pref
ip rule del pref 0 # delete default local table lookup rule
ip rout add ${ip3} via ${ip2} src ${ip1} table 100 # add correct route to some table
ip rule add from all lookup 100 pref 1000 # add rule to lookup new table before local table
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign different subnets to (1)-(2) and (3)-(4) pairs, and have host2 forward the packets from (2) to (3). The client on host1 will be connecting to address of (2), so local network stack will not know that the target server is actually running locally too.

Comment: Actually there are different subnets between (1)-(2) and (3)-(4). To use this solution I will need some forwarder on host2, that will listen for packets from interface (2) and send to interface (3) - through interface (4). Host2 is blackbox, so I cannot install any additional software there. Anyway client from host1 will be connected to server listening on interface (2), what is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: You need *something* to reflect packets sent from interface (1) to interface (3) - a pc acting as a router, a linksys junkbox setup with nat, anything. Get creative.

Comment: The problem is with sending packet out of host1 again. Even if routing is set to send all packets through default gateway set to interface (2) causes that packets send to second interface of the same device are not routed using default gateway. If I bind client socket explicity to interfece (1) packets are dropped by kernel (even tcpdump run on interface (1) don't see the packets). So the problem seems to be not with routing itself, but rather with local stack delivery.

Comment: That *something* needs to do either network address translation, or do proxying, so the destination address for the client is not on the same machine.