# How to send traffic between two nics on the same machine (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: linux, networking, namespaces, ubuntu-12.04

I have a machine with two nics, where I want to send data from one nic to the other, and I want this traffic to actually go through the switch. But when I do, the operating system notices that the two nics are on the same machine and is never actually sent out.

My initial thought is to create a network namespace and put one of the nics within this namespace, but I can not find any help about how to do that that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need the traffic to go through these NICs? If you elaborate a bit more, there might be another (more tricky) solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site about programing. You should look http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538081/how-to-avoid-routing-through-local-stack-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bypass the local routing table. Please see this answer:
[how to avoid routing through local stack in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538081/how-to-avoid-routing-through-local-stack-in-linux)